# Get source of Google App Engine published version

Tags: google-app-engine

Can I download my App Engine source code from Google?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I restore my source code that has been uploaded into Google AppEngine?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2479087/can-i-restore-my-source-code-that-has-been-uploaded-into-google-appengine)

Comment: No. That one is duplicate of this. This is about one year old.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update:** Google appengine now allows you to download the code

[Documentation here](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/uploadinganapp.html#Downloading_Source_Code).

(Duplicating answer from [the duplicate thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2479087/can-i-restore-my-source-code-that-has-been-uploaded-into-google-appengine/4367821#4367821))

Answer (score 2):

You can't - App Engine is not a source control system. There are handlers available that will let you download your source code directly, if you set them in app.yaml when you uploaded your app. They can't include files marked static, however, since they are uploaded to a separate location.

Answer (score 1):

Probably not. However, you can create a wrapper script around `appcfg.py` which will archive your source code and upload it along with everything else, then make that archive available on a protected part of the site.

An example of that is [here](http://www.cneophytou.com/2008/04/17/downloading-your-code-from-google-app-engine/).