# Can I restore my source code that has been uploaded into Google AppEngine?

Tags: google-app-engine, version-control, backup

I recently had a hard drive crashed and lost all of my source code. Is it possible to pull/checkout the code that I have already uploaded to Google App Engine (like the most recent version)?

Comment: Sorry to hear about your hard drive.  For future projects, try something like Github or Bitbucket for a free (as long as you keep it open-source) and easy way to keep a remote copy of your source code.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but that's I can't use those because what I'm making isn't going to be open source.

Comment: You can get a basic web hosting account that includes source control  (subversion) for $5 a month - i use geekisp.com but I'm sure there are plenty of others, maybe some are even cheaper for just svn.

Comment: github support private repositories, for a modest fee.

Comment: Did your app have the deferred handler registered? It might be possible to jigger something to recover your source via that, with some thought.

Comment: I use dropbox.com for insta-offsite backup. Just zip up my local repository and copy it there. Other free online data storage services exist.

Comment: projectlocker.com has outstanding SVN hosting that is free at the lowest service level. Off-site backups (as you now know) are absolutely and utterly essential.

Comment: this feature is now supported natively by Google App Engine; you should accept [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2479087/can-i-restore-my-source-code-that-has-been-uploaded-into-google-appengine/4367821#4367821) answer.

Comment: for updated completion - BitBucket currently supplies free accounts for non-OS software.

Comment: CloudForge is free, and includes SVN and GIT.

Comment: Further to @RichardLeMesurier's comment: GitHub allows 5 free private repos for Student accounts (need .ac.uk/.edu/etc email).

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Since I just went to all the trouble of figuring out how to do this, I figure I may as well include it as an answer, even if it doesn't apply to you:

Before continuing, swear on your mother's grave that next time you will back your code up, or better, use source control. I mean it: Repeat after me "**next time I will use source control**". Okay, with that done, let's see if it's possible to recover your code for you...

If your app was written in Java, I'm afraid you're out of luck - the source code isn't even uploaded to App Engine, for Java apps.

If your app was written in Python, and had both the [remote_api](http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/remote_api.html) and [deferred](http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/deferred.html) handlers defined, it's possible to recover your source code through the interaction of these two APIs. The basic trick goes like this:

1. Start the remote_api_shell
2. Create a new deferred task that reads in all your files and writes them to the datastore
3. Wait for that task to execute
4. Extract your data from the datastore, using remote_api

Looking at them in order:

## Starting the remote_api_shell

Simply type the following from a command line:

```
remote_api_shell.py your_app_id
```

If the shell isn't in your path, prefix the command with the path to the App Engine SDK directory.

## Writing your source to the datastore

Here we're going to take advantage of the fact that you have the deferred handler installed, that you can use remote_api to enqueue tasks for deferred, and that you can defer an invocation of the Python built-in function 'eval'.

This is made slightly trickier by the fact that 'eval' executes only a single statement, not an arbitrary block of code, so we need to formulate our entire code as a single statement. Here it is:

```
expr = """
[type(
    'CodeFile',
    (__import__('google.appengine.ext.db').appengine.ext.db.Expando,),
    {})(
        name=dp+'/'+fn,
        data=__import__('google.appengine.ext.db').appengine.ext.db.Text(
            open(dp + '/' + fn).read()
        )
    ).put()
 for dp, dns, fns in __import__('os').walk('.')
 for fn in fns]
"""

from google.appengine.ext.deferred import defer
defer(eval, expr)
```

Quite the hack. Let's look at it a bit at a time:

First, we use the 'type' builtin function to dynamically create a new subclass of [db.Expando](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/expandoclass.html). The three arguments to `type()` are the name of the new class, the list of parent classes, and the dict of class variables. The entire first 4 lines of the expression are equivalent to this:

```
from google.appengine.ext import db
class CodeFile(db.Expando): pass
```

The use of '**import**' here is another workaround for the fact that we can't use statements: The expression `__import__('google.appengine.ext.db')` imports the referenced module, and returns the top-level module (google).

Since `type()` returns the new class, we now have an Expando subclass we can use to store data to the datastore. Next, we call its constructor, passing it two arguments, 'name' and 'data'. The name we construct from the concatenation of the directory and file we're currently dealing with, while the data is the result of opening that filename and reading its content, wrapped in a db.Text object so it can be arbitrarily long. Finally, we call .put() on the returned instance to store it to the datastore.

In order to read and store all the source, instead of just one file, this whole expression takes place inside a list comprehension, which iterates first over the result of [os.walk](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.walk), which conveniently returns all the directories and files under a base directory, then over each file in each of those directories. The return value of this expression - a list of keys that were written to the datastore - is simply discarded by the deferred module. That doesn't matter, though, since it's only the side-effects we care about.

Finally, we call the defer function, deferring an invocation of eval, with the expression we just described as its argument.

## Reading out the data

After executing the above, and waiting for it to complete, we can extract the data from the datastore, again using remote_api. First, we need a local version of the codefile model:

```
import os
from google.appengine.ext import db
class CodeFile(db.Model):
  name = db.StringProperty(required=True)
  data = db.TextProperty(required=True)
```

Now, we can fetch all its entities, storing them to disk:

```
for cf in CodeFile.all():
  os.makedirs(os.dirname(cf.name))
  fh = open(cf.name, "w")
  fh.write(cf.data)
  fh.close()
```

That's it! Your local filesystem should now contain your source code.

One caveat: The downloaded code will only contain your code and datafiles. Static files aren't included, though you should be able to simply download them over HTTP, if you remember what they all are. Configuration files, such as app.yaml, are similarly not included, and can't be recovered - you'll need to rewrite them. Still, a lot better than rewriting your whole app, right?

Comment: Thank you for this. However, my app was written in Java. I'm sure that going off of the wiki style nature of stackoverflow, this will help someone else who did the same thing.

Comment: Alagu's answer is now more appropriate for this.

Answer (score 33):

**Update:** Google appengine now allows you to download the code (for Python, Java, PHP and Go apps)

Tool [documentation here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/appcfg).

Comment: Really Great news. This answer should be chosen.

Comment: Yea sure, except now it gives just a 404 error code, so perhaps its now better not chosen. No redirect. No nada. How much could the question change "How do I download" Why and I still wasting my time on this horrendously documented project?

Comment: @DanPride I'm having issues as well, did you ever get a solution?

Comment: Yes, I installed the old appcfg stuff, dowloaded it, then reinstalled gcloud. Not exactly a single click but it worked :)

Comment: The link points to 404. If there is an update perhaps you could point to the new location.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately the answer is no.  This is a common question on SO and the app engine boards.
See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1551127/download-source-code-of-deployed-gae-application) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1192128/how-to-download-google-appengine-uploadedapplication-files) for example.

I'm sure you'll be OK though, because you do keep all your code in source control, right?  ;)

If you want this to be an option in the future, you can upload a zip of your src, with a link to it somewhere in your web app, as part of your build/deploy process.

There are also projects out there like [this one](http://www.manatlan.com./blog/zipme___download_sources_of_your_gae_website__as_a_zip_file) that automate that process for you.

Comment: +1 for the zip file idea - nice to have even if using source control

Answer (score 4):

Found that you can run the following in your console (command line / terminal). Just make sure that appcfg.py is accessible via your $PATH.

```
locate appcfg.py
```

By default the code below prints out each file and the download progress.

```
appcfg.py download_app -A APP_ID -V VERSION_ID ~/Downloads
```

Comment: While code often speaks for itself, answers that only contain code and have no textual explanation, get flagged for the review queues. You can avoid this by adding a sentence or two of explanation.

Comment: Thanks. It's not often someone asks this nicely. Edited as such. Noted for future reference.

Comment: No problem, looks great :) I always just leave a comment and mark as "Looks OK" in the review queues. The explanations can be really helpful to people who need some context or want to learn more about what's going on, and it also helps people get here from search engines.

Comment: I'm trying this and it says `Fetching file list...` and then `Fetching files...` and then just stop and doesnt download anything.

Answer (score 2):

You CAN get your code, even in Java. It just requires a bit of reverse engineering. You can download the war file using the appengine SDK by following these instructions: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/uploadinganapp

Then you at least have the class files that you can run through JAD to get back to the source files (close to it, at least).

Answer (score 0):

if you're using python... you might be able to write a script that opens all the files in it's current directory and child directories and adds them to a zipfile for you to download

I don't know much about app engine or the permissions, but it seems like that could be possible

Comment: i am 95% sure that won't work in appengine, because you will be deploying your new "zipstuff" script into a whole new "virtual" filesystem.

Comment: It definitely won't work as described. I think you could pull it off if you have the deferred and remote_api handlers registered already, using a slightly different method.

Answer (score 0):

You have to revert to the earlier sdk, appcfg.py is not in the latest sdk. Kind of a pain, but it works. It should be far more prominent in the literature. Cost me an entire day.

Answer (score 0):

Update as of October 2020.

The current version of the Google App Engine SDK still includes the `appcfg.py` script however when trying to download the files from your site the script will attempt to download them into the root folder of your system.

Example:

```
/images/some_site_image.png
```

This is probably related to changes in appengine where your files might have
been in a relative directory before but they are no longer with the new versions
of the system.

To fix the problem you will have to edit the appcfg.py file in:

```
<path_to_cloud_install_dir>/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/appcfg.py
```

Around line 1634 you will find something that looks like:

```
full_path = os.path.join(out_dir, path)
```

The problem is with the `path` argument that for most files is a root directory.
This causes the join method to ignore the out_dir argument.

To fix this on a *NIX and MacOS type of system you will need to add a line before the above mentioned statement that looks like:

```
path = re.sub(r'^/', '', path)
```

This removes the `'/'` prefix from the path and allows the join method to properly
connect the strings.

Now you should be able to run:

```
google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/appcfg.py download_app -A <app> -V <version> 20200813t184800 <your_directory>
```