# How do I download the source code of a google app engine project?

Tags: google-app-engine

This seems like it should be very easy but I don't see a link to it anywhere.

How do I download the source code of a google app engine project?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2479087/can-i-restore-my-source-code-that-has-been-uploaded-into-google-appengine/

Comment: duplicate? more like quintuplet at least :)

Comment: which suggests maybe google might consider making it easier - like by adding a menu option for this to the launcher tool

Comment: Which is yet another example of how they don't give a rats ass about our time. Two hours now trying to do a simple download, Absolutely ridiculous. Three sets of documentation, none of which is current. Plus however many there are listed here.

Answer (score 23):

**Windows**

```
appengine-java-sdk\bin\appcfg.cmd -A <your_app_id> -V <your_app_version> download_app <output-dir>
```

**Linux**

```
./appengine-java-sdk/bin/appcfg.sh -A <your_app_id> -V <your_app_version> download_app <output-dir>
```

Comment: The command for windows contains a ";" after the "<your_app_id>" which breaks the command, causing no files to be downloaded. I can't edit this since it's a too small change.

Comment: If you are using microservices use the -M otherwise you will get an error "major version cannot be found"

Answer (score 17):

For completeness, using the Python implementation:

```
appcfg.py download_app -A $appID -V $appVersionNumber $downloadDirectory --oauth2
```

`--oauth2` is of course optional, you can omit it and provide your email + app-specific password (or your password, and then go implement two-factor authentication right after), but it's easier, and frankly there's no reason not to.

[Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/uploadinganapp#Python_Downloading_source_code).

Comment: In case you do not have appcfg.py then make sure you have app-engine-python extension installed: gcloud components install app-engine-python

Comment: This still is working.  However, to download 8000 files, it seems quite slow :(

Answer (score 7):

As of October 2019 you can simply go to --> App Engine --> Services and in the tool dropdown select 'source' and the source code is there

Comment: Doesn't answer the question. This does not allow download of source.

Comment: Maybe not Chris, but it allows you to see it, and that was all I needed. Everything else didn't work for me.

Answer (score 7):

Posting this since none of the listed methods above didn't take me to the code (by June 2021)

You could try accessing it through;

> Google Cloud Platform > Debugger > choosing the version of the
> Application from combo at top.

This will list the files of that version on the left pane. There is no way to download it automatically but you can copy-paste the code.

Hope you will find this helpful.

Answer (score 6):

App Engine actually recently added the ability for the developer who uploaded a given app version to [download its source code](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/downloading-source-code).

Comment: The page linked to above says the functionality is deprecated.

Answer (score 5):

IMHO, the best option today (Aug 2018) is:

Under the main menu, under Products, go to Tools -> Cloud Build -> Build history.

There, click the ID of the build you want (for me - the last one).

Then, in the opened window (Build details), click the "source" link, the download of your compressed code begins.

As simple as that.

HTH.

Comment: This approach doesn't work for App Engine in Standard Environment though.

Answer (score 4):

Working with App engine standard using Go, the debugger isn't available yet.

How I managed to download the source code for an existing service was to use the gcloud tool.

First: Get the version id of your service using the app engine console or running: `gcloud app versions list`

Second: use the version and service name and run: `gcloud app versions describe <versionID> --service=<service name>`

the describe parameter will give you the storage locations for your source files that looks like this:

```
cmd/main.go:
      sha1Sum: e3fe5848c2640eca7ac3591490e1debc2d3a9b09
      sourceUrl: https://storage.googleapis.com/<project>/<file id>
```

Third: you can then use the storage console, using the file id, to download the files you are interested in.

Answer (score 2):

this process based on java sdk
Its works for me...

1. Download Google cloud SDK
   `gcloud init`

[image]

2. Follow through process of logging in using your credentials
3. Enter following command from SDK

   C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\appengine-java-sdk-1.9.49\bin

[image]

4. Enter Following command to download source code

   appcfg.sh -A [YOUR_APP_ID] -V [YOUR_APP_VERSION] download_app [OUTPUT_DIR]

   Eg: `appcfg.sh -A my-project-name-1234 -V 2 download_app C:\Users\india\Desktop\my project`

Note: this progress based on java-appengine sdk so we use `appcfg.sh` instead of `appcfg.py`

Answer (score 2):

Things have changed since this question was asked so I'm adding an updated answer. Note that this only applies to **GAE Standard Environment**

Google has deprecated `appcfg.py` and so the previous responses `appcfg.py download_app` no longer works.

1. `gcloud` which is the SDK in use (it replaced `appcfg`) does not have the functionality to download your source code.
2. When you deploy your app via `gcloud app deploy`, it copies your source code to a bucket. The default bucket is `staging.<project_name>.appspot.com`. Your files will stay in this bucket for a maximum of 15 days before they are deleted. You can modify the rule so that the files are retained for longer or less time.
3. The file names in the bucket are encoded so you can't figure out what each file is unless you open it (i.e. download it). Google has a mapping of the encoded names to the original file names. To get this mapping, you run the `gcloud app versions describe` command and it will list the file names and their encoded names. To download the files, you have to manually click each url one by one. So essentially, you have to download each file manually and then use the mapping to rename them (or open the file, check the content and then rename them). Also note that downloading the files manually will not maintain the folder structure in which they were uploaded.
4. If you do not wish to go through all of the above hassles (imagine having to manually open each url for each file if you have a small to mid-sized project which has hundreds of files), our App - https://nocommandline.com - now supports downloading source code from the default bucket - `staging.<project_name>.appspot.com` (so far as your files are still there which means any deployment i.e update not older than 15 days from your current date unless you previously increased the deletion age on your staging bucket's lifecycle page).
5. In simple terms, you enter your project name, the version number and our App will take care of retrieving the original file name to encoded name mapping, automatically downloading the files and renaming them to the original names, while maintaining the folder structure. For more information, refer to https://nocommandline.com/help/#faq_download_source_code_from_gae.

Answer (score 1):

check if your app is uploaded with same email id that is in your app engine. if you are not sure then in app engine > control > Clear deployment credentials and then click on any project, deploy to sign in again then use this

appcfg.py download_app -A {app id from google app engine} -V {1} "{c:\path}" --oauth2_credential_file=C:\Users\{your account name}/.appcfg_oauth2_tokens

**change all {} to your needs**

Answer (score 1):

Log in to the console.developers.google.com
Select the project you want to download the code from (Google App Engine Standard Envoronment).
Go to the App Engine Dashboard.  Under Summary is Debug and Source.  Click on Source.
Select each file one at a time and copy it (highlight the code, copy and paste into your local editor.)
Select the next file....

Answer (score -4):

You need to use svn to checkout the files.

If you are on Windows, you can use [tortoise svn](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/) for your GUI end.

Here [are](http://cjcat.blogspot.com/2009/06/using-tortoisesvn-to-check-out-files.html) [tutorials](http://clipmarks.com/clipmark/072B85A5-D297-41D9-BD5F-413E7708D606/) on how to do it, here is [the related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41766/how-do-i-download-code-using-svn-tortoise-from-google-code).

Comment: Because you are talking about Google Code, not Google App Engine.