# How can I download my project source code from google cloud console

Tags: python, cloud

When i issued this command (appcfg.py -A rrrrr -V 1 download_app /C) to download source code from the Google Cloud Shell, I get this error message:

Python 2 is deprecated. Upgrade to Python 3 as soon as possible.
See https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/python2-sunset

To suppress this warning, create an empty ~/.cloudshell/no-python-warning file.
The command will automatically proceed in  seconds or on any key.

---

```
10:33 AM Host: appengine.google.com
10:33 AM Fetching file list...
Error 401: --- begin server output ---
1.434068975362424615
<ApiError 401, Message: "Rejected by creds_policy: Permission 'auth.creds.useNormalUserEUC' not granted to app-engine-appserver@prod.google.com, because it satisfies none of the 3 rules granting that permission. (Policy {type=creds, id=/apps/framework/auth/v0/mapping0/247afb42-c0c2-4579-9534-4d81ab6e915f}); RpcSecurityPolicy http://rpcsp/p/5frrBmXyY2vYXBQ1ey0O2q71nxZ-SEboQ9bDWATZ7oA
com.google.security.context.validation.CredsPermissionException: Rejected by creds_policy: Permission 'auth.creds.useNormalUserEUC' not granted to app-engine-appserver@prod.google.com, because it satisfies none of the 3 rules granting that permission. (Policy {type=creds, id=/apps/framework/auth/v0/mapping0/247afb42-c0c2-4579-9534-4d81ab6e915f}); RpcSecurityPolicy http://rpcsp/p/5frrBmXyY2vYXBQ1ey0O2q71nxZ-SEboQ9bDWATZ7oA ">
--- end server output ---
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`appcfg.py` is part of the old SDK which has been deprecated and no longer works ([source](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/appcfg-arguments)). Google has no direct replacement for `appcfg.py download`.

There are some possible work arounds as documented on this [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2497338/how-do-i-download-the-source-code-of-a-google-app-engine-project/28142173).

Our App, [nocommandline.com](https://nocommandline.com), also supports download with some caveats. See [full details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67352294/15211203) on our answer to that previous stackoverflow question. We also have an [article](https://nocommandline.com/blog/how-to-download-your-source-code-from-google-app-engine-standard-env/) on our blog about it. That article also gives you a tip on how to ensure your source code is available for download in the future.