# Build Google App Engine Java source from Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine, ant, osx-snow-leopard

I would like to try to build Google App Engine for Java from source.

I have tried this:

[image]
[image]
[image]

I don't know how to solve the javac Ant task. I am on Mac OS X 10.6.8.

The reason why I am trying to to create a Java Project from the source is that when I try to debug/step-into the sources downloaded from SVN, something is wrong in Eclipse and it does not track execution at the right code line. It seems to be executing "comment lines"? So I don't get an accurate tracking of the code path.

I think what I would ideally need is:

1) svn checkout command with matching REV number of latest SDK
2) wget command downloading matching jar

Comment: You really shouldn't need to build GAE from scratch just to get proper line numbers. Have you tried just _attaching_ the source?

Comment: You'd need the exact version of the source that they used to build the plugin you are using, but that should be available somewhere.

Comment: I have looked everywhere for matching source/jar... to no avail.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I restore my source code that has been uploaded into Google AppEngine?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2479087/can-i-restore-my-source-code-that-has-been-uploaded-into-google-appengine)