# Any workaround to reversing prohibit code downloads in google app engine?

Tags: google-app-engine

I accidentally prohibited code download on google app engine.

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/uploadinganapp#Downloading_Source_Code

I know the documentation states this is not reversible; does anyone know any work around, or have experience downloading code via google support?

**UPDATE**

I found this answer here: [Can I restore my source code that has been uploaded into Google AppEngine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2479087/can-i-restore-my-source-code-that-has-been-uploaded-into-google-appengine/), but can't seem to get it to work. If the download_app option is disabled, is all hope lost?

Comment: Delete the app, create a new one?

Comment: I don't have the source code unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

I assume this is exactly why this functionality is there, so that you can't download the source code in any way even if you have admin rights. I suppose the functionality is intended for when you don't trust the site admins with the actual source code. If there was a way around this, the whole point of having the functionality to disable source downloads would be defeated. Any method such as the one in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2479087/can-i-restore-my-source-code-that-has-been-uploaded-into-google-appengine/), if it would work, would be a security hole.

It may well be that the Python files aren't even kept at all, just the compiled bytecode.

You have to contact the person who has the source code to get it. There should be no way around this.